# How to traverse through an array of objects and find similar values in them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

In this object, there are 3 names with apple. Only one has a bool=true. So, it means that the apple with bool=true is the parent of the other two apples. How do I filter out the parent and the children when there are other key/value pairs?

I am a beginner at JavaScript and objects and am learning my way around it.

```
    var obj = [ 
    {
    id: 100,
    bool: true,
    name: apple,
    number: 123456
    },
    {
    id: 101,
    bool: false,
    name: banana,
    number: 34521
    },
    {
    id: 102,
    bool: false,
    name: apple,
    number: 98765
    },
    {
    id: 103,
    bool: false,
    name: apple,
    number: 56789
    },
    {
    id: 104,
    bool: true,
    name: cat,
    number: 34521
    }
    ];
```

Edit: Is it possible to find the children without mentioning the string 'apple' and just do it dynamically?

Actual result would be something like:

Children of apple = [102, 103]

Children of banana = null

Children of cat = null

Comment: just note, that the ones you have listed have `bool: false`, so I changed that logic in my answer ;) (and it's not a valid representation, as apples, cats and bananas are strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use following piece of code

```
obj.filter( v => !v.bool && v.name === 'apple' ).map( v => v.id ).join(',')
```

using `Array.filter` you can filter out the objects you are interested in, using `Array.map`, you can take the part of the object you are interested in. This result would then be an array, and joining them would result in a (in this case) comma separated list of ids that match

```js
const obj = [{
    id: 100,
    bool: true,
    name: 'apple',
    number: 123456
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    bool: false,
    name: 'banana',
    number: 34521
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    bool: false,
    name: 'apple',
    number: 98765
  },
  {
    id: 103,
    bool: false,
    name: 'apple',
    number: 56789
  },
  {
    id: 104,
    bool: true,
    name: 'cat',
    number: 34521
  }
];

console.log( obj.filter( v => !v.bool && v.name === 'apple' ).map( v => v.id ).join(',') );
```

Re-reading your question though, could also lead to different results (at least somewhat), like for example, get first all the parents, like:

```
Object.assign( {}, ...obj.filter( o => o.bool ).map( o => ({ [o.name]: [] }) ) )
```

this would create an object having properties like `{ 'apple': [], 'cat': [] }` and then map the potential children (I say potential, because your banana doesn't have any)

```
obj.filter( o => !o.bool)
```

and then reduce them into your starting object

```js
function getRootAndChildrenIds( obj ) {
  return obj.filter( o => !o.bool).reduce( (agg, cur) => {
    if (agg[cur.name]) {
      agg[cur.name].push( cur.id );
    } else {
      console.warn( cur.name + ' doesn\'t have a parent' ); // banana doesn't exist as a parent
    }
    return agg;
  }, Object.assign( {}, ...obj.filter( o => o.bool ).map( o => ({ [o.name]: [] }) ) ) );
}

const obj = [{
    id: 100,
    bool: true,
    name: 'apple',
    number: 123456
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    bool: false,
    name: 'banana',
    number: 34521
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    bool: false,
    name: 'apple',
    number: 98765
  },
  {
    id: 103,
    bool: false,
    name: 'apple',
    number: 56789
  },
  {
    id: 104,
    bool: true,
    name: 'cat',
    number: 34521
  }
];

console.log( getRootAndChildrenIds( obj ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is an array, not an object. I wouldn't call it 'obj' because that is incorrect and might be causing you confusion.

Look up the .filter() function in javascript. I think it will solve exactly what you're trying to do.

You could do something like this:

```js
array.filter(arrayObj => arrayObj.name === 'apple' && arrayObj.bool === true)
```

That should return all objects that have a name of 'apple' and bool equal to true.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to find the children without mentioning the string 'apple' and just do it dynamically?

Comment: You can change 'apple' with a variable if that's what you mean. I'm not sure what you mean about finding 'children'. Do you mean finding an index in the array?

Comment: @snowbird you could check out the second part of my answer, that would find all the children and give out a warning for items without children, but for starters, I think this code is pretty good to give you something to learn to work with